# Basic group algebra exercise

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, equivalence-relations

I'm working on this abstract algebra problem that was given as homework to me, I'm in my first year of university and have a semester's background in basic abstract algebra. Here is the problem:

Let $G$ be a group. $\forall x \in G$ let $C(x)$ be $g\mid g \in G: gx=xg$.

Define the equivalence $\sim \forall x,y \in G$ if there exists $g \in G$ such that $g^{-1}xg=y$. 

$\forall x \in G$, $[x]$ shall define the equivalence class of $x$. Let $D_x$ be the set $C(x)g\mid g\in G$. 

Define $\psi: D_x \rightarrow [x]$ such that $\psi(C(x)g)=g^{-1}xg, \space \forall g \in G$.

Show that:

(a) $\psi$ is well defined.

(b) $\psi$ is a bijection.

(c) if $G$ is a finite group and $x \in G$, then $|[x]|$ divides $|G|$.

It's not clear to me how to demonstrate point a, that is, if $g_1,g_2 \in G$ such that $\psi(C(x)g_1) = \psi(C(x)g_2)$, then $C(x)g_1 = C(x)g_2$.

Also, in point b surjectivity is quite simple, but injectivity does not seem as intuitive.

Comment: I did a small bit of MathJax editing to this question. Note the use of \mid and \sim in MathJax code.

Comment: to write $\{ X \},$ use "\{ X \}." here is link for MathJax: http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/93/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm new here as you can see!

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Is this a homework question? If so, please provide information regarding your mathematical background, and especially your own attempts to solve the problem: that way we can taylor the hints and solutions to better suit your needs.

Comment: As a note what you cite as what you should do for a is not welldefined-ness, it's injectivity. Welldefined-ness is the other way around (viz. if the images are different then so are the preimages).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* (1). $C(x)g = C(x)h \Leftrightarrow gh^{-1} \in C(x) \Leftrightarrow gh^{-1}x = xgh^{-1} \Leftrightarrow h^{-1}xh = g^{-1}xg.$

(2). Injectivity follows from above. For surjectivity follows from the definition of $\sim.$

(3). Use Lagrange's Theorem.